# Assistance needed to login using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

[Here's the link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ORGJ.png)
This is what I've recorded using Blazemeter chrome extension for my product login[Rails-app]. Should I make the equal and same sampler HTTP requests as its in the picture? It only contains two POST requests and remaining are GET requests.

Comment: I'm a mere beginner in JMeter so help me get through this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to analyze those post  requests and identify those parameters related to username/password.

You can use CSV data config in Jmeter and from there you can provide a list of username/passwords that Jmeter can use to login for multiple users.

Additionally, you need to check if there are extra security parameters sent along with login request. If there is any then you will need to handle that as well.

Also it is recommended that you add following elements to your test plan and learn their usage...

- cookie manager
- header manager

You can check following blog for further examples on login via Jmeter

http://sjpknight.com/recording-a-login-script-with-jmeter/

Answer (score 0):

Rails applications in majority of cases have [CSRF protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), it results in an additional request parameter called `authenticity_token` which dynamic value needs to be extracted from previous response and passed along with next request.

If you look into http://nov26.freshpo.com/support/login page source you'll be able to see the token:

[image: Ruby CSRF Token]

So you need to design your test as follows:

- GET Request to nov26.freshpo.com/support/login page

  - Post Processor - extract the authenticity_token into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- POST Request to nov26.freshpo.com/support/login page with username, password and aforementioned token

In order to get the token I would suggest using [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) configured as follows:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `token`
- CSS/JQuery Expression: `meta[name=csrf-token]`
- Attribute: `content`

other inputs may be left as they are.

Refer extracted value as `${token}` where required:

[image: JMeter passing dynamic parameter]

See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) article for more detailed information on how to bypass CSRF protection in your JMeter test

Comment: I can't get a better explanation than this. Thanks a ton Dude !!